# Laravel whereIn list values not found in query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

When building a query to find multiple values from a model, eloquent would look something like this:

`return Contact::whereIn('user_name', explode(',', $userNames)`

But let's say that the value for `userNames` is `['foo', 'bar'];` but I only have `foo` as a valid username, is there a way to get `bar` (all failed to find) out as part of the same query without having to compare the result `->get()` against the request?

Comment: So you want to filter out the list of usernames from the request data? Please be more precise with what you need.

Comment: So you want a list of contact objects with that username even if no such contact exists in the database?

Comment: I'm working on the same project as this handsome human being. We're looking for a way to get 2 lists back - one with the matches and one with the usernames that was not found.

Comment: @Sydgren in this case you need to use `whereIn` and `whereNotIn`. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to get the query to return the list of username that doesn't exist from the given condition. But you could do this.

```
$allUserNames = explode(',', $userNames);

$validUserNames = Contact::whereIn('user_name', $allUserNames)
    ->pluck('user_name')
    ->toArray();

$invalidUserNames = array_values(array_diff($allUserNames, $validUserNames));
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I was afraid of since I didn't find anything useful in the source code, the problem is that it is bad when the results are really big, since collection tend to be really bad to handle big amount of data

Comment: You don't have to use collections. Select just the `user_name` column and cast the query result to an array. I just showed the example  using pluck.

Comment: Yeah, but I think I need to find a better way to handle this since that collection because the query result will be millions and it not optimal nor fast to run it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array diff to remove the unvalid value form the select region, and you lost the `->get()` to get the results;

```
return Contact::whereIn('user_name', array_diff(explode(',', $userNames, ['bar']))->get()
```

Comment: @jycr753 I missed understand your quesiton, I edited.